# Add new element to object after it created

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, object

Hello I need make a object in JavaScript. It will show a array-object field named "Cities" then inside of Cities it will give city name, id, key then District array object then it will have town data for that district and city.

How can I add new city after I created an object?

To be clear:

```
{
  "Cities": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "Name": "İstanbul",
      "Key": "asdfas",
      "District": [
        {
          "ID": "aa",
          "Name": "bb",
          "Key": "12",
          "Towns": [
            {
              "Id”:”aa”,
              “Name:”X Town”
            },
            {
              “Id:”bb”,
              “Name:”B Town”
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It will be like that.

How can I add a new City to it after I created?

İf I do like:

```
obj.Cities={ 
"ID":"New City",
"Name":"X City",
"Key":"2121",
"District":[
{
.....
}]
}
```

Like that it's deleting first data and replacing it. I want the 2nd city. How can I add new city after I created?

Comment: `obj.Cities.push(aNewCity)`

Comment: `obj.Cities.push( { "ID":"New City", ... } )`

Comment: @SheikYerbouti  

Thanks for reply. But when i try push it says : Obj.Cities.push is not a function

Comment: @kmoser Thanks for reply. But as i said its say Obj.Cities.push is not a function on React project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assigned your `array` :

```
obj.Cities={ 
"ID":"New City",
"Name":"X City",
"Key":"2121",
"District":[
{
.....
}]
}
```

which is incorrect and in this situation `Cities` is an `object` not an `array`. You should assigned it with `[ ]`:

```
obj.Cities=[{ 
"ID":"New City",
"Name":"X City",
"Key":"2121",
"District":[
{
.....
}]
}]
```

And for adding new items to `array`, you can try **[`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** method of array:

```
obj.Cities.push({"ID":"id",
"Name":"cityName",
"Key":"cityKey"});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But when i try push it says : Obj.Cities.push is not a function.

Comment: @UğurcanUçar Updated the answer. Please check it again.